# Why isn't this for loop writing each element to a file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

Here is my code:

```
var data = require('./campSample.json');
var dataArray = data.resultset.result;
var fs = require('fs');


for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
    fs.writeFile("./campList", dataArray[i]["-facilityName"], function (err) {
        if(err){
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm trying to get the for loop to go through each item in the array, get the facilityName, and write the facilityName to a file. When I run the above code, it's only writing the facilityName of the first item in the array. Is there a better way to do this? The campSample.json I'm working with is only a sample. The actual array I'd like to use has about 4000 items in it. Here is the contents of campSample.json:

```
{
  "resultset": {
    "-count": "4904",
    "-resultType": "campgrounds",
    "result": [
      {
        "-availabilityStatus": "N",
        "-contractID": "GA",
        "-contractType": "STATE",
        "-facilityID": "530145",
        "-facilityName": "A. H. STEPHENS STATE HISTORIC PARK",
        "-faciltyPhoto": "/webphotos/GA/pid530145/0/80x53.jpg",
        "-latitude": "33.5633333",
        "-longitude": "-82.8966667",
        "-shortName": "C145",
        "-sitesWithAmps": "Y",
        "-sitesWithPetsAllowed": "Y",
        "-sitesWithSewerHookup": "N",
        "-sitesWithWaterHookup": "Y",
        "-state": "GA"
      },
      {
        "-availabilityStatus": "N",
        "-contractID": "OH",
        "-contractType": "STATE",
        "-facilityID": "960023",
        "-facilityName": "A.W. MARION STATE PARK",
        "-faciltyPhoto": "/webphotos/OH/pid960023/0/80x53.jpg",
        "-latitude": "39.6336111",
        "-longitude": "-82.8747222",
        "-shortName": "P023",
        "-sitesWithAmps": "Y",
        "-sitesWithPetsAllowed": "Y",
        "-sitesWithSewerHookup": "N",
        "-sitesWithWaterHookup": "N",
        "-state": "OH"
      },
      {
        "-availabilityStatus": "N",
        "-contractID": "NRSO",
        "-contractType": "FEDERAL",
        "-facilityID": "72346",
        "-facilityName": "ACKER ROCK LOOKOUT",
        "-faciltyPhoto": "/webphotos/NRSO/pid72346/0/80x53.jpg",
        "-latitude": "43.0523056",
        "-longitude": "-122.6456111",
        "-shortName": "ARCL",
        "-sitesWithAmps": "N",
        "-sitesWithPetsAllowed": "Y",
        "-sitesWithSewerHookup": "N",
        "-sitesWithWaterHookup": "N",
        "-state": "OR"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the expected result in this file `"./campList"` ?

Comment: How about concatenating `string` and `fs.writeFile` only once ?

Comment: For the above json sample, expected output is as follows:

A. H. STEPHENS STATE HISTORIC PARK 
A.W. MARION STATE PARK 
ACKER ROCK LOOKOUTTE HISTORIC PARK 

But now that I see the order, the current code is actually just writing the third item's facilityName, Acker Rock...

Comment: Don't `return console.log(err)`. All you're doing there is returning `undefined`. Just log the error and that's it. And make sure that each filename is unique if you're going to use writeFile as async operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, you need to append the content to file, so following code will work

```
var data = require('./campSample.json');
var dataArray = data.resultset.result;
var fs = require('fs');

for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
    fs.appendFile("./campList", dataArray[i]["-facilityName"]+'\r\n', function (err) {
        if(err){
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah ha! This worked for me. Thank you very much for your help. The for loop is now writing the facilityNames to a new file in list format. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should collect all the names beforehand, then write all that names into `./campList` with just a single IO request.

```
var names = dataArray.map(function(result) {
  return result["-facilityName"];
}).join('\n');
fs.writeFile("./campList", names, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: This seems like a much better way to go than appending and iterating, for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 1):

From `writeFile` docs:

> Note that it is unsafe to use fs.writeFile multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback. For this scenario, fs.createWriteStream is strongly recommended

Additionally:

> Asynchronously writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already exists.

Comment: createWriteStream is giving an error, Unknown encoding: a. h. stephens state historic park